# Are there any canon examples of texts written in elvish?

Tags: lore, forgotten-realms, languages

I’m referring to the Elven language of the Forgotten Realms, usually written with the Espruar script. Are there any examples of messages, poems, paragraphs, ...? More specifically, ones that make sense in the language, not just random letters from the Espruar script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Dragon magazine article by Sean Reynolds, titled "An Elven Lexicon" (Dragon #279, January 2001). It has examples of the words and short sentences along with their translations. An example:

> The elf says the magic sword we want is in the lich's tomb.
>
> Kesir hinual kerym lerret quen teshuel aul morenial mormhaor.
>
> [Elf speak sword magic we take in tomb important-undead.]

You can read it on the Dragon magazine archive at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/DragonMagazine260_201801/DragonMagazine279#page/n55/mode/2up).

Comment: Cool! It’s a shame that most of it is Pidgin, but I do believe that a few phrases in there can be considered proper language. Maybe others will find more examples (if any exist).

Answer (score 1):

There is one in Sword Coast Adventurers Guide, page 108. I don't remember the translation.

Also check the cover of 3rd Edition Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting. The outer ring of the symbol contains an Espruar inscription, "We remember cities now in ruin and forests murdered, yet still we sing to the stars and hope for renewal".

For the record, the Dethek inscription inside the same ring says "The secret fires of our hearts burn with the memory of wars lost and heroes slain, but like the stone from which we came, we endure"

Comment: I’ve read the SCAG inscription, sadly it’s in English and reads: “a true friend as the trees and water are true friends”. And I’ve tried to read the inscription on the cover of the 3.0 book, but I’ve yet to find any screenshots with high enough resolution to properly discern the characters.